# Cosa significa "subire" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Ma il mio amore è Paco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Il colonnello incrociò le sue carte, Paco stette con sei, il colonnello gli scoprí un bel sette. – **Subisco**, – rantolò mio zio passandosi una mano sugli occhi.

Ho cercato il verbo "subire" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il suo significato in questo passaggio. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

**Aggiornamento:**

Ecco alcuni estratti dal racconto precedenti a quello riportato prima che parlano del gioco di carte che si sta svolgendo:

> Ci fu un paio di smazzate. Paco perdeva, malgrado la sua capacità di calcolo Maggiorino non poteva dir quanto, e perché è sovrumano seguire il gioco in tutti i suoi alti e bassi e perché mio zio teneva non sul tavolo ma in grembo il suo mucchio di denaro. 
>          Finalmente il banco gli diede tre colpi buoni. Il colonnello glielo batté, solo ed intero. Paco ebbe paura e lo passò, voltandosi colse negli occhi di Maggiorino un lampo di approvazione. Racca offrí per il banco e se lo aggiudicò. Vinse ancora e mio zio bestemmiò grosso. Ma non aveva fede in quel banco e gli puntò contro un terzo della vincita che gli aveva procurato. Vinse ancora il banco. Paco gli ripuntò contro il doppio e riperse. Ripuntò mille lire e quel banco infernale diede il sesto colpo favorevole. Il colonnello crollava impercettibilmente la testa in direzione di mio zio, il quale: «Sto rovinandomi contro il mio banco buono! – urlava dentro di sé. – Un banco che bastava per Gemma e… e quel deficiente cornuto di Maggio che m’ha approvato!» 
>          Madama controllò che rimanesse un’ultima mano nel mazzo agonizzante. Paco ripuntò le sue ultime duecento lire e riperse. Le orecchie gli ronzavano, ma senza impedirgli di cogliere i commenti di certi spettatori.
>          [...] 
>         Ricominciarono. Nuovi curiosi salivano dal cortile, ma la sala era ormai intasata e i primi arrivati si degnavano di soffiare a quelli pigiati sulla scala o sul ballatoio notizie sull’andamento generale del gioco. Racca vinceva, il colonnello forse era in pari, tutti gli altri perdevano: Paco secondo nella graduatoria dei perdenti, a ruota del proprietario di Valdivilla. Questi motteggiava come se nulla fosse, chiamava Racca Lucifero, ogniqualvolta gli batteva banco annunziava che andava a visitar Lucifero a casa sua. 
>          Dopo un lungo intervallo il banco ridiede a Paco tre colpi favorevoli. Era non piú di un brodino per un ammalato grave ma, per poco che durasse, poteva diventare panacea. I pidocchietti avevano già avanzato puntatine contrarie, poi il colonnello tamburellò con le dita e chiese banco solo.

Subito dopo il passaggio prima riportato si spiega come lo zio Paco, che ha perso tutti i suoi soldi in questo gioco, intima il suo amico Maggiorino di andare a casa sua a cercarne di più.

Comment: Sembra tipo un'ammissione di resa, come dire "Ho perso".

Comment: Il gioco è [“sette e mezzo”](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sette_e_mezzo)

Comment: Potresti riportare anche il gioco e il seguito della partita?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket: Fatto.

Answer (score 3):

Qui si riferisce, da quanto si può capire, ad una partita a carte. "Subisco" ha qui il significato di "accetto la sconfitta" nella partita.

[Subire:](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/subire.shtml)

> - Detto di persona, dover sopportare qlco. di negativo o spiacevole, SIN *ricevere, patire*: ***subire***  un torto, ***una sconfitta***;

(Sabatini Coletti)

Comment: Ha senso, tuttavia l'espressione che appare come esempio di uso del verbo "subire" nel Sabatini Coletti è "subire una sconfitta", mentre questo personaggio dice "subisco" e basta.

Comment: Beh, dai. La gente non parla come un libro stampato. E dire subisco perdendo a carte si riferisce chiaramente ad avere perso la partita. A proposito... ”essere sconfitti o battuti” a carte è un’espressione molto comune.

Comment: È allusivo e canzonatorio - ironico: invece di dire "ho perso" preferisce "subisco" così da collegare la sconfitta al gioco con il ruolo di colonnello, come se avesse perso la mano di gioco a causa di ordine impartito da un diretto superiore. Gli italiani hanno il gusto dell'iperbole ironica.

Comment: @MrPk - potrebbe essere, questo dipende dal contesto del racconto. Oppure si rifà al gergo militare, dove "il subire" fa parte del linguaggio quotidiano.

Comment: @Gio certamene, infatti mi riferivo al ruolo del colonnello ovviamente nell'esercito, ma è corretto specificare

Answer (score 1):

Come già detto nella risposta di @Gio [subire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/subire/) significa

> 1. Essere costretto a sopportare cosa che sia imposta, non voluta né gradita, e che comunque comporti sacrificio, dolore, danno:

Volendo andare oltre l'espressione mi ricorda il ben più famoso "Obbedisco" pronunciato da Giuseppe Garibaldi, [così ricordato dall'Agenzia Ansa](http://www.ansa.it/sito/notizie/cultura/libri/2016/07/21/obbedisco-quando-garibaldi-si-fermo_b6dfcfba-1a7f-43f1-9195-37c69660eee7.html):

> "Obbedisco": una semplice parola capace di cambiare corso alla storia
> del nascente Regno d'Italia e posticipare di cinquant'anni
> l'annessione del Trentino.

Con ciò voglio dire che spesso queste semplici parole racchiudono in sé una moltitudine di significati, sentimenti. Qui si vuole enfatizzare l'ammissione di resa, come dire "Ho perso e ne subisco le conseguenze".

Comment: Non so se andrei a scomodare Garibaldi per una semplice partita  a carte. Comunque l’estensione o l’uso figurato del significato letterale  delle parole è un aspetto  molto diffuso nell’uso della lingua.

Answer (score 0):

Se, come ha detto egreg nel suo [commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/cosa-significa-subire-in-questo-brano#comment21817_9808), il gioco è sette e mezzo, "subisco" potrebbe essere una variante regionale del più comune "Sto". Questo gioco consiste nel raggiungere sette punti e mezzo scoprendo una carta alla volta da un mazzo da 40 carte (quattro semi, per ogni seme sette numeri e tre figure). Come spiegato [qui](http://www.cavallore.it/index.php/giochi/33-sette-e-mezzo):

> Valori delle carte:
>
> - Tutte le figure valgono ½ punto.
> - Tutte le altre carte valgono il loro valore nominale, l'Asso vale 1, il Due vale 2, e via dicendo.
> - La matta, ossia il Rè di Quadri/Danari, può assumere, a piacere del giocatore che lo riceve, un valore intero oppure ½ punto, non può però valere ad esempio 3 e ½.

e poi:

> il primo giocatore, a destra del cartaio (se il gioco si svolge in senso antiorario, altrimenti quello alla sinistra), controlla la sua carta, per prima cosa deve effettuare una scommessa in denaro, la carta e la sua esperienza lo guideranno nell'entità della puntata. Poi ha due opzioni di gioco.
>
> - Può chiedere un'altra carta, dicendo "CARTA!".
> - Può fermarsi e passare il turno dicendo **"STO!"**.

In questo gioco, rilanciare e perdere è meno vantaggioso di perdere e basta. In questo caso, direi che lo zio è sicuro di perdere la partita e per questo non rilancia, a fronte di un sei di Paco e di un sette del colonnello, ma per essere sicuri bisognerebbe sapere come finisce la partita e che carta aveva lo zio.

Comment: Lo zio e Paco sono la stessa persona.